# Wallonia or Walloon Region?

Tags: translation, geography

What is the preferred way to refer to la Wallonie in English -- Wallonia or Walloon Region?

Comment: I think the reason  people sometimes  don't say Wallonia is often because they think people will not know where it is. So, rather than "Wallonia which is a region in Belguim" it is quicker to say " the Walloon region of Belguim".

Comment: I agree with @choster. It depends on your readers. Always write for your intended audience.

Answer (score 0):

***Wallonia*** appears to be  more common than  ***Walloon region***, see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wallonia%2CWalloon%20region%2C%20Walloon%20Region&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWallonia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWalloon%20region%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWalloon%20Region%3B%2Cc0):

[Wallonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallonia):

> a region of Belgium. Wallonia is primarily French-speaking, and accounts for 55% of the territory of Belgium, and a third of its population.

(Wikipedia)

[Walloon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/walloon):

> A member of a people who speak a French dialect and live in southern and eastern Belgium and neighbouring parts of France.
>
> (mass noun) The French dialect spoken by the Walloons.

(ODO)